# Please help me tikz picture in beamer class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have a tikz picture. It work smoothly in my thesis file. But when I put it to frame, it make error please help me.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=quad,indention=10pt]{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
init/.style={
  draw,
  circle,
  inner sep=2pt,
  font=\Huge,
  join = by -latex
},
squa/.style={
  draw,
  inner sep=2pt,
  font=\Large,
  join = by -latex
},
start chain=2,node distance=13mm
]
\node[on chain=2] 
  (x2) {$x_2$};
\node[on chain=2,join=by o-latex] 
  {$w_2$};
\node[on chain=2,init] (sigma) 
  {$\displaystyle\Sigma$};
\node[on chain=2,squa,label=above:{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Activate \\ function}}]   
  {$f$};
\node[on chain=2,label=above:Output,join=by -latex] 
  {$y$};
\begin{scope}[start chain=1]
\node[on chain=1] at (0,1.5cm) 
  (x1) {$x_1$};
\node[on chain=1,join=by o-latex] 
  (w1) {$w_1$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=3]
\node[on chain=3] at (0,-1.5cm) 
  (x3) {$x_3$};
\node[on chain=3,label=below:Weights,join=by o-latex] 
  (w3) {$w_3$};
\end{scope}
\node[label=above:\parbox{2cm}{\centering Bias \\ $b$}] at (sigma|-w1) (b) {};

\draw[-latex] (w1) -- (sigma);
\draw[-latex] (w3) -- (sigma);
\draw[o-latex] (b) -- (sigma);

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (x1.north west) -- node[left=10pt] {Inputs} (x3.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you include the picture obtained in the thesis?

Comment: You haven't loaded the appropriate TikZ libraries. Add `\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}` in the preamble, and the code compiles.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot. So if i have a text on top and want to scale tikpicture to fit on frame. Do you know any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to load the appropriate TikZ libraries. Add

```
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
```

to the preamble, and the code compiles.

If you want to scale a `tikzpicture`, you can add options

```
transform shape,scale=<factor>,
```

to the `tikzpicture` environment. For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  transform shape,scale=.5,
  <other options>
]
  <drawing commands>
\end{tikzpicture}
```

will produce the following result:

[image]